# Python meta class with custom metaclass behavior

Tags: python, oop, metaclass

I am playing with metaclasses in Python 2.7. So I created a code that looks like this:

```
class M(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, parents, attrs):
        print 'In meta new'
        return super(meta, meta).__new__(meta, name, parents, attrs)

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'In meta init'

    def __call__(cls, *attr, **val):
        print 'In meta call'
        return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = M

    def __new__(cls):
        print 'In class new'
        return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print 'In object init'

    def __call__(self):
        print 'In object call'
```

But the output confuses me:

```
A()

In meta new
In meta init
In meta call
```

Somehow class methods __ new __ and __ init __ were overridden, so interpreter just skip them. Can anyone explain this stuff?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `super()` incorrectly. The first argument to `super()` is supposed to be the *class itself*, not the instance of it.

```
return super(meta, meta).__new__(meta, name, parents, attrs)
```

should be...

```
return super(M, meta).__new__(meta, name, parents, attrs)
```

and so on for the other `super()` calls - the first argument should be the class they're within; the second is the actual instance.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because I do not use the origin Python mechanism - `cls()`, which guaranties automatic working of the `__new__` and `__init__` methods, it is overridden by metaclass `__call__` method, which doesn't do the same.